# Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have installed react-router-domV6-beta.

By following the example from a website I am able to use the new option useRoutes I have setup page routes and returning them in the App.js file.

After saving I am getting the following error:

> Error: Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a
>  component.

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import react, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import _ from "lodash";
import Cast from "./Cast";
import list from "./list";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import DetailLayout from "./DetailLayout";

function App() {
  const [charnames, setCharnam] = useState("");

  function charname(names) {
    setCharnam(names);
  }

  function castDetail(everycast) {
    return (
      <Cast
        key={everycast.id}
        url={everycast.url}
        name={everycast.name}
        castp={charname}
      />
    );
  }
  const cc = charnames;
  const p = "/" + cc;
  //const p="/haha h";
  const res = p.replace(/ /g, "");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="overview">{list.map(castDetail)}</div>
      {/* <DetailLayout /> */}
      {console.log(charnames)}
      <Router>
        <Cast />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path={res} element={<DetailLayout />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Cast.js

```
import react from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Cast(props) {
  function setpath() {
    props.castp(props.name);
  }
  const path = "/" + props.name;

  return (
    <div className="cast">
      {/* <Link to="/about">About</Link> */}
      {/* <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink> */}
      <NavLink to={path}>
        <img onClick={setpath} src={props.url} />{" "}
      </NavLink>
      <p>{props.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this error simply says wrap your useLocation() inside

```
 <Router>  </Router>
```

all react-router-dom hooks and functions should be used inside

```
<BrowserRouter> </BrowserRouter>
```

otherwise they simply don't work

Comment: A bit tougher to do with [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router), isn't it?

Comment: any solutions to use useLocation() with createBrowserRouter?